# C: Dynamic memory allocation - error of output

Tags: c, io, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to write a simple program that takes specific input, dynamically allocates it, outputs it and frees. The thing is it does not output it properly. The input's style is the following:

The first line is the number of lines that I need to read - i.

Then there are i lines. On each line I read one word, then an integer n that shows how many integers will proceed next and then there come n integers.

For example,

```
2
yellow 2 32 44
green 3 123 3213 3213
```

Explanation:

1st line - there must come 2 lines.

2nd and 3rd line - word + number of integers + integers.

My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int n; /* n - number of words */
    char **words; /* words - array of keywords */
    int **data;
    scanf ("%d\n", &n);

    words = (char **) malloc (n * sizeof (char *));
    data = (int **) malloc (n * sizeof (int *));

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        words[i] = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char));
        for (j = 0 ;; ++j)
        {
            words[i] = (char *) realloc (words[i], sizeof (char) * (j + 2));
            scanf ("%c", &words[i][j]);

            if (words[i][j] == ' ')
                break;
            else if (words[i][j] == '\n')
                --j;

        }

        words[i][j] = '\0';
        data[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
        scanf ("%d", &data[i][0]);

        for (j = 0; j < data[i][0]; ++j)
        {
            data[i] = (int *) realloc (data[i], sizeof (int) * (j + 2));
            scanf ("%d", &data[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf ("%s ", words[i]);
        printf ("%d ", data[i][0]);
        for (j = 0; j < data[i][0]; ++j)
        {
            printf ("%d ", data[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        free (words[i]);
        free (data[i]);
    }
    free (words);
    free (data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `sizeof (char)`? Hint: How many `char`s fit in a `char`? What's the point in multiplying or dividing by 1?

Comment: [Don't cast malloc.](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html). Please adjust your indentation so that it's formatted consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = (int **) malloc (n * sizeof (char *));` This doesn't make sense... The return value points to an `int *`, yet you're allocating in multiples of `sizeof (char *)`. These two aren't required to have the same representation, which implies that they're not required to have the same width. See [this page](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) for more info. PS: [Don't cast malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html). While you're there, read the rest of the website. It'll prevent you from encountering future common problems. In the mean time, I'll assume you meant `data = malloc(n * sizeof *data);`.

`n`, by the way, should probably be a `size_t` instead of an `int`. To recieve a `size_t` using `scanf`, use the `%zu` format specifier. An example of this is provided below.

---

```
    data[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
    scanf ("%d", &data[i][0]);
    for (j = 0; j < data[i][0]; ++j)
    {
        data[i] = (int *) realloc (data[i], sizeof (int) * (j + 2));
            scanf ("%d", &data[i][j]);
    }
```

In this poorly indented example of code (which nobody wants to read, because it's poorly indented), a problem exists. The problem would normally go undetected because nobody wants to read it until it's correctly formatted, unnecessary casts are removed and consideration is given to the silly logic it presents.

The loop is supposed to end when `j == data[i][0]`. In the first iteration of the loop, `data[i][0]` changes, so the condition for the loop changes. Hence, this loop isn't doing what you want it to do. Perhaps you meant to write something like this:

```
    size_t count;
    /* Note how scanf returns a value, and when that value isn't 1 an assertion error
     * is raised? An exercise for you is to get that assertion error to raise, or read
     * the manual... */
    assert(scanf("%zu", &count) == 1);

    /* Note how malloc doesn't need a cast? */
    data[i] = malloc(count * sizeof data[i][0]);
    for (j = 0; j < count; ++j)
    {
        /* Note how count never changes, in this loop? */
        assert(scanf("%d ", &data[i][j]) == 1);
    }
```

While we're on this topic, you'll notice that I added a space to the end of the last `scanf` format string. That space consumes as much whitespace as possible from `stdin`. The reason for this is, presumably for the same purpose as the broken code in your previous loop, to read and discard any `'\n'` characters before reading the next item "word":

---

```
    words[i] = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char));
    for (j = 0 ;; ++j)
    {
        words[i] = (char *) realloc (words[i], sizeof (char) * (j + 2));
        scanf ("%c", &words[i][j]);
        if (words[i][j] == ' ')
            break;
        else if (words[i][j] == '\n')
            --j;
    }
    words[i][j] = '\0';
```

The possibility for leading `'\n'` characters is now virtually eliminated, with the exception of the user maliciously pressing enter without entering a word. `malloc` casts removed, and a more sensible allocation algorithm in vision, I presume you meant:

```
    size_t j = 0;
    words[i] = NULL;
    for (int c = getchar(); c >= 0; c = getchar()) {
        /* Reallocate when j is a power of two, eg: 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16...
         * ... and double the size of the buffer each time
         */
        if (j & (j - 1) == 0) {
            char *temp = realloc(words[i], j * 2 + 1);
            /* hint: Check *all* return values */
            assert(temp != NULL);
            words[i] = temp;
        }

        if (strchr(" \n", c) == NULL) { break; }
        words[i][j] = c;
        j++;
    }

    words[i][j] = '\0';
```

Comment: my fault with indentation - in the temporary version of question that is shown on the bottom where i create it it was giving false indentation, so i was adding some of tab characters, then it turned to an error

Comment: thanks, silly mistake about allocating to character pointers, was brushing up my C, haven't written code in it for ages

Comment: by the way, why have you included "while ()" at the end of for loop?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev I've added onto the end of my function to deal with an error in your use of `realloc`. You may wish to review comments in the code I provided. They might be insightful.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev That was a mistake.

Comment: why are you reallocating with powers of two?

Comment: To reduce the overhead of calling realloc, and potentially of realloc calling malloc, malloc finding new memory, realloc copying from old block to new block, realloc freeing old block from *n* where *n* is the number of characters in your word, to *log n*... Less calls, less allocations, less copying.

Comment: Think about it: If you're allocating a new, larger buffer for each of 512 characters, then the first character gets unnecessarily copied from old to new 512 times. With my code, it gets copied 10 or 11 times.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev I'm glad you understood that. SIZE_MAX is required to be (size_t) -1 which is represented in binary entirely using 1's. The algorithm used here is neat because it uses numbers that are also represented in binary entirely using 1's. That makes it easy to tell if the object you have allocated is already the maximum size, allocate the next object to be a continuation and continue as though it's simply a new item.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev Better yet is an approach to program without buffers. I gather you hyaven't considered using an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) to store the numbers as data, using the words "green" and "yellow" as keys. Some associative arrays don't require storage of their keys. For example, consider a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table); The user could input as many characters as he/she wants up until he/she presses enter, and your program would read each keystroke using `getchar()` and calculate an index to an array on the fly.